# Accept only specific integer at compile-time

Tags: c++, c++17, assertion, compile-time, requirements

Some named requirements like [Allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) want you to implement quite generic methods, e.g. `Allocator::allocate(int n)`. For my specific case I only want to implement an argument `n=1`, and if possible I'd it to fail at **compile-time** if some other integer was supplied.

So far I have not found any reliable solution. I only care about GCC and Clang.

- This works fine in GCC, but it not in Clang ([Godbolt](https://www.godbolt.org/z/DW_m3r)):

  ```cpp
  struct OneAndOnlyOne {
      constexpr OneAndOnlyOne(int v) noexcept {
          // static link-time error in Clang for any value of v unless -O2 is supplied:
          if (v != 1) _you_must_supply_a_one();
      }
  private:
      void _you_must_supply_a_one();
  };
  ```
- assert makes it a runtime-problem ([Godbolt](https://www.godbolt.org/z/j9X-Uw)):

  ```cpp
  struct OneAndOnlyOne {
      constexpr OneAndOnlyOne(int v) noexcept {
          // fails only at runtime:
          assert(v == 1);
          (void) v;
      }
  };
  ```
- static_assert does not work, either: ([Godbolt](https://www.godbolt.org/z/tqQeNV)):

  ```cpp
  struct OneAndOnlyOne {
      constexpr OneAndOnlyOne(int v) noexcept {
          // "error: 'v' is not a constant expression"
          static_assert(v == 1);
      }
  };
  ```
- There does not seem to trick to turn the argument into a template parameter ([Godbolt](https://www.godbolt.org/z/TvYGms)):

  ```cpp
  template <int> struct FailUnlessOne;
  template <> struct FailUnlessOne <1> {};

  struct OneAndOnlyOne {
      constexpr OneAndOnlyOne(int v) noexcept {
          // "error: 'v' is not a constant expression"
          constexpr FailUnlessOne<v> test;
          (void) test;
      }
  };
  ```

Is there something I overlooked, or is it not possible at all to test an argument at compile-time?

Comment: You overlooked the fact that `v` is a parameter that can be called anywhere, from any translation unit, and when compiling the other translation unit that compiler knows nothing, whatsoever, what's in this translation unit, so what you're seeking to do is logically impossible in C++.

Comment: `constexpr OneAndOnlyOne(std::integral_constant<1>) noexcept`?

Comment: @Jarod42, "no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'std::integral_constant<int, 1>"

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, the definition has to be definition known at compile-time.

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/lK4gf5).

Comment: In that case the only way I can think of is to make it a template parameter, rather than a function parameter.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, well, if I didn't have to conform to an interface, I'd omit the argument altogether. :)

Comment: Then a runtime assertion is pretty much the only portable way to go, here.

Comment: David Stone proposes a fix for this in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1045r1.html

Comment: @erlc, that's exactly what I want. The `tuple::operator []` example looks like a great. I hope it gets adopted into C++20!